# How do I mark an inventory item as trash?

Tags: borderlands-2

I noticed that while at a store, there is an option to "Sell Trash".

[image: store screen]

I figure it will be similar to Kingdoms of Amalur in that I can mark items as junk and sell them all in one simple action.

**Is this what it means to "Sell Trash?"  How can I mark an item as trash?**

It doesn't seem like it's an option in the inventory screen or the inspection screen.

[image: inventory screen]

Answer (score 60, accepted):

At least on the **PC version**, you can mark an item as a **Favorite** or as **Trash** by moving your mouse to the right side of the item where a star or X will appear. (The hidden hover areas appear vertically above each other.) Clicking on these will mark them as either a favorite or as trash respectively.

[image: inventory screen with favorites and trash marked]

A favorite item <s>cannot</s> can still be sold but has a nice marker on it so it stands out better.  Trash items can be sold in bulk at stores (by going to the Buy menu and pressing <kbd>Delete</kbd> on PC, clicking **Left Stick** on the console), so you can get rid of your trash items easily at the store.

The **console versions** or using a **gamepad** will have dedicated buttons to toggle these settings.

Using a **gamepad** or playing the **Xbox 360** version, you can toggle these settings pressing the **Left Stick**.

[image: gamepad enabled]

I imagine the PS3 version will use **L3** to toggle the settings.

Comment: It's a shame that there doesn't seem to be a shortcut to do this on the PC version.

Comment: This seems to be buggy on the PC version. After marking items, scrolling up/down on the list seems to unmark them.

Comment: Yeah, it's slightly annoying. Though they're still marked, it's just that the icons are just hidden. If you leave the screen and come back, trash items that you marked will stay marked. It will only happen if you change any of them and scroll.

Comment: @Nick there's multiple scroll bugs on PC, sometimes hovering will select an item above/below your cursor. Exit and reopen the menu and they're fixed

Comment: A faster way to bring back the icons after scrolling (if you recently added them) would be to change the sort order and then back.  This still keeps you in the "backpack view" while restoring the icons.

Comment: @BenBrocka The scrolling bug is fixed when you place your mouse somewhere else highlightable and then back on the first backpack item, you don't need to close the view.

Comment: @Nick: Ah, it looks like they've fixed the scrolling bug in the most recent patch.

Comment: @Nick: Correction, they've almost fixed it. The first item in the list doesn't keep its state. Everything else seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

On the **Nintendo Switch**, the shortcut button to mark an item as favorite or trash is **L3**.