# What is this red cross next to my weapon?

Tags: borderlands-2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I mark an inventory item as trash?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84680/how-do-i-mark-an-inventory-item-as-trash)

I'm not even sure about when it appeared there.  It doesn't seem to do anything when I click it.  Any idea ?

[image]

Comment: Related: [How do I mark an inventory item as trash?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84680/how-do-i-mark-an-inventory-item-as-trash)

Comment: When you click it with a mouse, it does remove Trash status, but the icon stays because your mouse is on top of it. Make sure to move the mouse away. Also there's a bug on PC, where immediate changes to Trash/Favorite status disappear (but are not lost) when you scroll the inventory.

Comment: @OrcJMR God, I hate that bug. It happens consistently, every time I use the inventory. Don't see how it could have been missed or considered unimportant!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That indicates the weapon has been marked as trash.  If you go to a vendor and on the  **Buy Screen** sell all trash (<kbd>Delete</kbd> on PC, <kbd>Left Thumb Stick</kbd> on 360), it would then sell this item and any others marked trash.  Note that <kbd>Left Thumb Stick</kbd> will mark an item as trash on the 360 (presumably on the PS3 as well, ditto for selling all trash) but there is no hot key to do it on the PC; you must use the mouse (just hover over that side of the weapon and the the symbols will appear "greyed out").

Above the "X" is a Star you can click to mark an item as a favorite, though this purely cosmetic.

Comment: And it has to be the buy screen -- on the sell screen, it doesn't work.

Comment: @Crowbeak that's true.  Not sure why they did it like that.

Comment: I found it a bit counter-intuitive at first. However, now I think that if I can only have it on one or the other, the buy screen is the better option. Open vending machine, sell stuff, and go. Bam.

Comment: It's more that it should be on *both* screens, on the off chance someone wants to look at something before selling all.

Comment: I agree. It's such a minor detail, though, in what's otherwise a much improved user interface. I can't make myself hate it.

Comment: @Crowbeak - you can flag stuff on the regular inventory screen, so as I'm going round picking stuff up I'm flagging trash as a go, then it's one click to dump it at the next vending machine. If I run out of space I just drop the cheapest trash-marked item

Comment: Same here. It's much nicer than last game, and the fact that you can favorite weapons makes them stand out so you don't accidentally sell that shock submachine gun you keep on hand just in case.