# Is there a way to mark a weapon as trash at the moment I pick it up?

Tags: borderlands-2

Related: [How do I mark an inventory item as trash?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/84680/how-do-i-mark-an-inventory-item-as-trash)

I'm in the (very) early game, but I've got a couple guns that I really like.  What this means is that I've got a LOT of guns that I immediately mark to sell as trash.

It would be super awesome if I could just pick these inferior guns up and throw them into a side pocket of my backpack, never to be looked at again.

**Is there a shortcut to immediately mark a gun as trash at the moment I collect it, without going into the inventory menu?**

Additional information: I'm playing on a PC and that's the platform I'm interested in, but solutions for consoles would be nice as well.

Comment: Are you talking about a Windows/Mac keyboard macro?

Comment: @CyberSkull - anything would be fine really

Comment: What I meant was what platform are you running the game on? That has a big effect on the keyboard/gamepad shortcuts.

Comment: It would be best if an answer covered all platforms.

Comment: @SadlyNot: I have the distinct feeling it won't cover PS3 or 360, if there's even a solution for Macs and PCs.

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do this too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think such a thing exists (ability to mark the weapon as you pick it up). But my system is pretty simple: I evaluate guns soon after picking them up - those I like get a star, those I don't get red X. Later, when I pick up more guns, I can easily find them because they aren't marked at all.